# How to express the "multiple" of one thing's advantage over another？

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-requests, academia

For example, car A runs at a speed of **30 km/h**, and car B at a speed of **90 km/h**. How can I express the multiple of B faster than A?

> B has **3** times advantage over A in speed.

> B has **2** times advantage over A in speed.

> B is **3** times faster than A.

> B is **2** times faster than A.

Which of the above statements is appropriate. What are the better expressions in academic writing?